# how to use javascript to populate value in a dropdownlist as selected from a textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsex" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>male</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>femle</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>unknown</asp:ListItem>        
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and I also have a textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

so I want to use JavaScript to realize that when I type in the textbox male, the dropdown list will show male selected, or type female, the dropdown list will show female selected. if none of them, then alert no such option.
can anybody help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TextBox1").change(function () {
            alert($("#TextBox1").val());
            alert("Test");
            $("#DropDownList1").val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First define values attribute with your dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlsex" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="male">male</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="female">femle</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="unknown">unknown</asp:ListItem>        
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Include the JQuery library in your .aspx form

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var txtCtrl = $('#<%=txt.ClientID%>');

        //On focusing out the textbox I'm setting value of dropdown.
        //You can change it to anything else here
        txtCtrl.focusout(function () {
            var ddCtrl = $('#<%=ddlsex.ClientID%>');
            ddCtrl.val(txtCtrl.val());
        });
    });
</script>
```